# Lists are not displayed correctly on Windows version of Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I've noticed that, at least for my Windows installation of PyCharm, list elements are not displayed in the correct order in the variables pane of the Python console. For example, the elements of the list `some_list` shown below are displayed in the order of 1, 0, 2, instead of 0, 1, 2.

[image]

This problem doesn't occur on the mac build of PyCharm. I couldn't find any published reports of this problem. Does anyone know if this is a known bug?

I updated my PyCharm verion to the latest beta release (2018.1.3) and the problem still persists. I'm on Windows 7.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: hmmm ... I do not seem to experience that same issue ... using 2018.1 PRO (build # 181.4203.547) I tested both 3.6 and 2.7 ... i did not test python3.5 (I am also not using the IPython settings)

Comment: I wonder if it's b/c you're using the Pro version. Do you remember if you had the issue on any non-pro windows versions of pycharm?

Comment: So, it is re-ordering but retaining the index also ?

Comment: Yep, PyCharm is showing the indexes/element in the incorrect order - It knows what element is element 0, 1, 2, etc., but it just doesn't know to display 0 first, then 1, etc.